# Anyone else having trouble accessing dynamic windows partitions from Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, windows, raid, mdadm, microsoft

I have been trying to access my striped software raid disk from Ubuntu for at least six months. I know there are guides out there, but they are a bit hard to follow, at least for me.

How can I access these partitions?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer using my interpretation from the Ubuntu Man pages.

First install `ldmtool`:

```
sudo apt-get install ldmtool
```

Now I just run a few commands on boot and bam! I have access to any windows dynamic disk.

```
sudo ldmtool scan
sudo ldmtool create all
```

I created a little script I run every time I log in called `mount.sh`

If someone knows how to not require the input of the sudo password, and add the script as a startup application, that would be a great help.